# Fill laravel select with eloquent model using pluck

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to fill a laravel (version 5.5) select with data from the eloquent model.

So I'm geting data like this:

```
$types = Type::pluck('name', 'id');
```

And returning to the view:

```
return view('something')->with('types', $types->all());
```

So here is my view select:

```
{{ Form::select('type', $types, NULL, ['id' => 'myselect', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Well, the problem is: each option is an object, like this:

> {"id":1,"name":"test","created_at":"2017-12-29 18:09:45","updated_at":"2017-12-29 18:09:45"}

And what I want is: the value equal to the id and the name equal to the name

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show whole controller method. Also, you're getting collection of objects when you do `@dd($types)` in the view?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting collection of objects when I dumpdie.

The whole controller method is in portuguese, I would have to translate all of it, but what really matters is:

public function edit($id)
    {
        $tipos = Tipo::pluck('nome', 'id');
        
        return view('something')
            ->with('types', $types)
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
return view('something')->with('types', $types->all());
```

To:

```
return view('something')->with('types', $types);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alexey, but it makes absolutely no difference on the view :( still getting the whole object on each select option

Comment: @GabrielAugusto you definitely do something else with the variable, because `pluck()` can't return these results. Please show the method if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$types = Type::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

return view('something', compact('types'));
```